# change format of Date field in view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date-format

May be a simple question but i input dates into my model like so

```
<%= f.label :published_on, 'Published Date' %>
<%= f.date_select  :published_on, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

When creating the column from a migration i specified the column as :date

To output i use

which displays in this format

```
2013-01-01
```

How can i get this date to display

1st january 2014

I can convert a string into a date with this helper for example

```
def date_format(date)
date.to_date.strftime("#{date.to_date.day.ordinalize} %b %Y")
end
```

But doing it the other way around is throwing me

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
date.strftime('%e %B %Y')
```

visit this for more formats http://strfti.me/